# How to handle multiple dynamic form with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I want to have a page on my website where I can upload files. For each file I want to have a name and a category.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose a file")]
    [Display(Name = "File")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Category")]
    public string cat { get; set; }
```

This is my model. I want to have some dynamic form, what I mean is a form with a button that allows the user to add another form on the page to upload multiple files with a name and a category for each file. I've done this with Symfony2, but I have no idea how to do it with ASP.NET. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: The keyword here is `Editor Template` or `Partial View`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a bare minimum example based on [this blogpost](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). For demo purposes, I've named my model `Foo`. So whenever you read this, this should be your model with file, name and cat properties.

First, add `https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/` to your project.

Then, add a partial view to your Views folder. I've named mine "_AddFile.cshtml":

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Foo

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("files"))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Note, the `Html.BeginCollectionItem("files")`, this is creating a collection, that is later grouped together and bound to your model named "files".

Our controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Initialize the view with an empty default entry
    var vm = new List<Foo> {
        new Models.Foo {
            Cat ="foo",
            Name =" bar"
        }
    };
    return View(vm);
}

//this calls your partial view and initializes an empty model 
public PartialViewResult AddFile()
{
    return PartialView("_AddFile", new Foo());
}

//note "files" name? The same as our collection name specified earlier
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostFiles(IEnumerable<Foo> files)
{
    //do whatever you want with your posted model here
    return View();
}
```

In your view, use this form:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Foo>

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostFiles","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="FileEditor">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_AddFile", item);
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add File", "AddFile", null, new { id = "addFile" }) <input type="submit" value="Finished" />
    </div>

}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#addFile").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) { $("#FileEditor").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });
        })
    </script>

}
```

The foreach loop renders a partial View for each model entry, in our case just one with a default entry.

The javascript loop then calls our PartialView and renders an empty template below the existing ones.

A call to submit, then lets you deal with your files in any way you want:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 1):

At first create another model like following:

```
public class fileListModel{
    IList<yourModel> fileList {get;set;}
}
```

Then in the razor view create form like this way:

```
@model fileListModel
<form>
    //dynamic html(you can also use partial for this). When button will be clicked append following html using jquery $(form).append()
    @{var key = [use some random id or guid]}
    <input type="hidden" name="fileList.Index" value="@key" />
    <input type="text" name="fileList[@key].name" value="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="fileList[@key].cate" value="Category" />
    <input type="file" name="fileList[@key].file" value="Upload"/>
    // end dynamic html

    @{ key = [use some random id or guid]}
    <input type="hidden" name="fileList.Index" value="@key" />
    <input type="text" name="fileList[@key].name" value="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="fileList[@key].cate" value="Category" />
    <input type="file" name="fileList[@key].file" value="Upload"/>
    // end dynamic html
</form>
```

Now create a controller action method to accept the fileList:

```
public ActionResult upload(fileListModel fileList){
    //save them to db
}
```