# Save Data from HTML table into SQL Server in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**Below is my Razor View**

```
    <tr id="CGT_Row">
                    <td class="noGutter">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.clsCGT.CGT_Visit_Date, new {@id="dp1",  @class = "input-sm text-center date", @readonly = "true" }) </td>
                    <td class="noGutter">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.days_of_CGT, new List<SelectListItem>
                                           {
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="1 Day",Value="1 Day"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="2 Day",Value="2 Day"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="3 Day",Value="3 Day"},
                                           },
             new { @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown" })
                </td>
                <td class="noGutter">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.clsCGT.village_Name, new { @class = "input-sm text-center" })</td>
                <td class="noGutter">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.fo_Name_CGT, TempData["Staff_List"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @id = "ddl_CGT_fo", @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown", @style = "width:auto;" })</td>
                <td class="noGutter">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.member_attendence_CGT, new List<SelectListItem>
                                           {
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="Less than 100%",Value="Less than 100%"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="100%",Value="100%"}
                                           },
                     new { @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown", @style = "width:auto;" })
            </td>
            <td class="noGutter">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.process_follow_CGT, new List<SelectListItem>
                                           {
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="n",Value="n"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="y",Value="y"}
                                           },
                             new { @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown", @style = "width:100%;" })
        </td>
        <td class="noGutter">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.CGT_timing, new List<SelectListItem>
                                           {
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="As per time",Value="As per time"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="Delayed",Value="Delayed"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="Reschedule",Value="Reschedule"},
                                           },
                                     new { @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown", @style = "width:auto;" })
    </td>
    <td class="noGutter">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.fo_comm_to_client, new List<SelectListItem>
                                           {
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="n",Value="n"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="y",Value="y"}
                                           },
                                             new { @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown", @style = "width:100%" })
</td>
<td class="noGutter">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.member_house_verification_CGT, new List<SelectListItem>
                                           {
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="n",Value="n"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="y",Value="y"}
                                           },
                                                   new { @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown", @style = "width:100%;" })
</td>
<td class="noGutter">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.documentation_complete_CGT, new List<SelectListItem>
                                           {
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="n",Value="n"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="y",Value="y"}
                                           },
                                                   new { @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown", @style = "width:100%;" })
</td>
<td class="noGutter">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clsCGT.CGT_conducted_for_3_days, new List<SelectListItem>
                                           {
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="n",Value="n"},
                                               new SelectListItem { Text="y",Value="y"}
                                           },
                                                   new { @class = "input-sm", @actor = "DropDown", @style = "width:100%;" })
</td>
<td class="noGutter">@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.clsCGT.CGT_remarks, new { @class = "input-sm" })</td>
</tr>
```

This is bind with  model and onclick of a button I can save this into database without any problem .

But my need is I want to add another row too before saving it into database

So I used jquery to add another row in table below this row

```
function Create_New_Row(id) {

    var row; var table;
    var closeBtn = '<td><a onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg fa-border" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#e90029"></i></a></td>';
    if (id == 'CGT_Row')
    {
        row = '#CGT_Row';
        table = '#tbl_CGT tr:last';
    }
    else if (id == 'GRT_Row')
    {
        row = '#GRT_Row';
        table = '#tbl_GRT tr:last';
    }
    else if (id == 'Disb_Row')
    {
        row = '#Disb_Row';
        table = '#tbl_Disb tr:last';
    }
    var v = $(row);
    var html = '<tr>' + v.html() + closeBtn + '</tr>';
    $(table).after(html);

    $('[id^="dp"]').datepicker({
         format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
         autoclose: true
    });

}
```

This will look like this

[image: See this image]

Click to add new row - to add new row into table

Save Details - To save all these rows into database

The Problem is - Only first row is bound to model , which I can access to save data, how to get data from other rows(added later ) coz they are just duplicate copy of first row html only without model binding

For example - if I filled 4 rows than on Click of Save Details all 4 rows should be saved in database (SQL Server)

**Update :1**

**For Viktor Oleksyshyn**

Below is my js code to convert this table values into array and pass it to controller

```
function Table_to_Array(id) {

    if (id == "CGT_Data")
    { var tbl="tbl_CGT"; }
    if (id == "GRT_Data")
    { var tbl = "tbl_GRT"; }
    if (id == "Disb_Data")
    { var tbl = "tbl_Disb"; }

    var myTableArray = $('#'+tbl+' tr').map(function () {
        return $(this).find(':input').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
    }).get();
    return myTableArray;
}

function send_to_server(id)
{
    var iden = id;
    var result = Table_to_Array(id);
    var data = {
        data_holder: result,
        Category: id
    };

    var params = {
        url: '@Url.Action("Send_to_server", "Annex1")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional : true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) { alert('Ok! It worked.'); },
        error: function (result) { alert('Warning! It failed.'); }
    };
    $.ajax(params);
}
```

It does pass the array to controller but also show alert failure - (set on error: function [alert('Warning! It failed.'); ])

Comment: Are you using ajax  for saving?

Comment: I think using jQuery to generate tables dynamically is quite complicated. A single partial view which rendered for every row added by AJAX call (use indexing) & using custom model binder to save rows data is more preferred over fully JS/jQuery solution.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto can you  refer any post for this approach ?

Comment: @PowerStar , no . For right now I don't have any idea to save this data . In Asp.net It is doable with gridview which allow us to add footer template functionality , But i don't know how to do that in mvc

Comment: Is your post method handled from jquery ajax or from the server side itself? If  you can please share it.

Comment: @Guru Try reading this as reference: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/. Basically in Razor view it can be used, just use `return PartialView` for every AJAX call made & append HTML element to the table.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Thanks for your response , But all it shows is how to use partial view for dynamic addition or row functionality , It does not say anything about how to save data from all those row . Adding row is not a problem , saving  them is the main issue

Comment: @Guru - you can use begincollectionitem in mvc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700557/mvc-5-dynamic-rows-with-begincollectionitem

Comment: I've also posted an answer to a similiar question using Tetsuyas linked blog post as a refernce: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160894/how-to-handle-multiple-dynamic-form-with-c-sharp/45164126#45164126

Comment: @Marco - does "files" in beginCollection need to be a property in model ?

Comment: not in the model. But if you name your collection "files", then the parameter in your action method needs to be named files as well or it will not be picked up

Comment: I did that and only getting one collection , other collections are getting lost

Comment: @Marco , please search for "MVC Html.BeginCollectionItem is not creating collection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you are using
@Html.**TextAreaFor**(m => **m.clsCGT.CGT_remarks**...
That would be rendered to something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="CGT_remarks" ... />
```

When you making a copy of row - you did not change the name of the input. So in the example you have three collections of inputs with same names. When you submitting a form "system" uses names as identifiest for request parameters, so - 1 unique name for parameter.
What you can do for simple workaround:

1. If you have simple **form.submit** or Ajax call with **data: form.collection** - you can change the control names by adding some suffix at the end and then manually parse it on controller via **this.Request.Form**. I do not really like this solution, so I hope the second one fits.
2. You can also collect your objects from inputs by jquery selector into array. Then, just use Ajax call and pass your array to controller [like in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I was thinking about second option too , but above everyone said its the most worst way to do this , see my updated question , it post data to controller but also show alert which is set on error function

Comment: What is your Action returns? If it returns null, please try return this.Json(true);

Comment: Adding Json(true) helped here , Thanks